# Team city 8.1 connect to TFS (VS2013)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

I am setting up TeamCity continuous integration. While creating VCS Root, I am getting the error:

> Test connection failed in ProjectBuilder :: BuildConfiguration. TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://abc.visualstudio.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/Components.

1. Already installed Team Explorer on the machine where teamcity server is running.
2. Trying: To log in to hosted TFS use "ALTERNATE AUTHENTICATION CREDENTIALS" and add "##LIVE##\" prefix to your username (email address). option

Please also let me know what should be the VCS root :URL and root under TFS settings in Team City.  Should it be pointed to .sln file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a clue from here:
[Using TF.exe with Team Foundation Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828429/using-tf-exe-with-team-foundation-service/14829097#14829097)

And changed my server Url to:  https://abc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection. and it worked!!